# sparkSession.sql throwing NullPointerException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have two scala classes as part of my spark-sql job i.e. Driver.scala and ExtractorOne.scala.

Driver.scala passes different parameters like sparkSession object and etc to different extractors like ExtractorOne.scala and etc.

In Extractor classes I am extracting data from oracle and writing as parquet files in hdfs location.

As part of business logic I have to call sparkSession.sql() to perform some operations. But inside the extract() method of Extractor/calling class sparkSession is causing a Nullpointer exception ...so I tried to check it in the calling function by calling sparkSession.sql("show tables").show()   it gives the results i.e. no issue with object. Where as when call the same i.e. sparkSession.sql("show tables").show() inside called function it is throwing Nullpointer exception ... any idea what am i doing wrong here?

'
   Driver.scala

```
    val spark = ConfigUtils.getSparkSession( ...); //spark session initialization successful

      val parquetDf = spark.read.format("parquet"); // able to read parquet file data and got the dataframe.


      val extractors :  LinkedHashMap[String, (DataFrameReader, SparkSession, String, String,String,String) => Unit] = Utils.getAllDefinedExtractors(); 
      ///ExtractorOne.scala  ExtractorTwo.scala ..etc are extractors as shown in other scala file


      for ( key:String <- extractors.keys){

                extractors.get(key).map{

                    spark.sql("show tables").show()  ///output

                   fun => fun(ora_df_options_conf,spark,keyspace,key.trim(),"","")
             }
            }
```

'

Output of  spark.sql("show tables").show() :::

```
 spark.sql("show tables").show()



> Blockquote

+--------+---------+-----------+
|database|tableName|isTemporary|
+--------+---------+-----------+
+--------+---------+-----------+
```

But samething gives error in ExtractorOne.scala

'

ExtractorOne.scala

```
def extract(oraOptionDfConfig: DataFrameReader, sparkSession: SparkSession, keyspace: String,
        columnFamilyName: String, fromDate:String , toDate:String ) : Unit ={

        val company_df  =  ..// some opeartion to read the data from oracle to company_df
        val  dist_df = company_df.distinct("id")

         company_df.createOrReplaceTempView("company")

         dist_df.foreach( row =>{

           if(row.anyNull){

           }else{


              val sqlQuery:String = s" select * from company  where id='%s' and quarter='%s' and year='%s' ".format( row.get(0) , row.get(1) , row.get(2))



              sparkSession.sql("show tables").show() ///output...

              var partitionDf = sparkSession.sql(sqlQuery)

              partitionDf.show(1)

               writeAsParquet(...) ///save as parquet file/s
           }


}
```

'

Output of  sparkSession.sql("show tables").show() :::

ERROR :

'
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:142)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:140)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:641)
        at com.snp.extractors.CompanyModelValsExtractor$$anonfun$extract$1.apply(ExtractorOne.scala:126)
        at com.snp.extractors.CompanyModelValsExtractor$$anonfun$extract$1.apply(ExtractorOne.scala:113)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)

```
  '
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you cannot use the SparkSession in executor-side code (i.e. in a `dist_df.foreach` -loop), the Spark Session is null in this case (it only lives on the driver)

Comment: sir how to handle this ?? what alternatively i have , any sample please ?

Comment: intestingly i am using sparkSesssion.sql ()  with out (for) loop  in another scala class , it is working fine.

Comment: where can read or get more on , how and what to segreate at driver side and executor side ? i.e. best practices of coding for optimal performance.

Comment: sir still this gives same error ... 
  ```

 dist_company_model_vals_df.foreach( row =>{
           
             var partitionDf = company_model_vals_df.select("*").where( col("model_id").===(row.getString(0)).and(col("fiscal_quarter").===(row.getString(1))).and(col("fiscal_year").===(row.getString(2))) )   ```` what is wrong here ?

Comment: @user3252097 you are doing the same here, you cannot use dataframes within executor code (`df.foreach` is executed on the executors), dataframes only live in the driver. Workaround : collect dataframe to the driver first, AND read about the basics of spark

Comment: @ Raphael Roth thank you sir , any sample or url to understand it better

Comment: I have also faced same error it's resolved with .collect()  here is the sample.    input.foreachRDD { rdd =>
      rdd.collect().foreach { message => { But as we use .collect() all the data will be transferred it driver memory which is causing performance issue, application is stuck